# Calendar for React small version

Tags: reactjs, react-calendar

I need to create this React component:

[image]

I'm very new working with React but I know react-calendar (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar) is one of the most popular options.

Is there any way to create a short version of the calendar as displayed in the wireframe? Would anybody recommend another library?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Material-UI library. It has many ready-made components and their customization is easy

Comment: But anyway I need something to give me the data structure of the calendar; months, days...etc.